# How to print output in Single line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to know how to print output in a single line

I want to print it like: 1234

instead of

```
1
2
3
4
```

Code:

```
 # n = (get in from user)
 i=1
 while (i<=n):
     print (i,)
     i +=1
```

Comment: `print(i, end='')` in Python3

Comment: you should use print(i,end = ' ')

Comment: Why did you tag your question `python-2.7` if you're using Python 3?

Comment: @khelwood could be that he has a future import?

Comment: @norok2 Could be. Either way, it should have said in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This may help :

For **Python 3**:

```
print(i,end='')
```

For **Python 2**:

```
print(i),
```

Comment: OP asks for Python 2, not Python 3.